# How can I remove Proprietary Sources

Tags: apt, software-center, proprietary

I only enabled "main" and "universe" repos, but still proprietary software like "steam" are enabled and shown in the list, how can I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are confused in this sense. First, if you want keep enabled only **main** and **universe** repositories, check your **`/etc/apt/sources.list`** to look something like this:

```
##
## ...comments...
##
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security universe main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates universe main
```

Then, from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal), run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to resynchronize the package index files from their sources.

After all of these are done, if you still have doubts that a certain package is from proprietary sources, you can check with the following command:

```
apt-cache madison package_name
```

For example:

```
$ apt-cache madison firefox
   firefox | 23.0+build2-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main amd64 Packages
   firefox | 23.0+build2-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main amd64 Packages
   firefox | 20.0+build1-0ubuntu2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
$ apt-cache madison wallch
    wallch | 3.01-0ubuntu2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Thanks, seems that software-center doesn't follow apt rules.

Answer (score 0):

If your proprietary software was installed via a .bundle file (such as it is with VMware player - my own current learning nemesis), then it may have an uninstaller command that you have to run (for example vmware-uninstall) ... check in the documentation for the products you installed from the developer's website ... they should have a getting started guide or something that explains how to uninstall it at a command line