# How can I refuse commercial drivers?

Tags: command-line, drivers, proprietary

When installing the operating system, I indicated the point to use commercial drivers. Now I want to completely abandon the commercial drivers in favor of the free ones. How can i do this?

Comment: Those are not drivers but some audio codecs and restricted fonts.

Comment: [Richard Stallman](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093752/how-to-make-sure-im-not-using-any-proprietary-software-after-installation) might help.

Answer (score 2):

Any drivers(commercial) will be in 'software and updates' under additional drivers.  Can enable or disable drivers from there.

Comment: If you are talking about the codecs they can be removed by removing 'ubuntu restricted extras' in software centre.

Comment: The problem is that it is not installed even if you check that box. It's hard to tell what exactly is installed.